# Capitalization of an acronym that starts a parameter

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, code-formatting

I have a variable that indicates the length of time the UI can be idle.  I have elected to call this variable `UITimer`.  I want to pass the variable into my classes constructor and then store it off in a local field.

What is the proper way to do the casing of this?  We use the common convention of a parameter not being capitalized.  So should I do this:

```
uITimer
```

or this?

```
uiTimer
```

Also, we do an underscore and lowercase first letter for our fields.

Should that be declared like this:

```
 private int _uITimer
```

or like this

```
 private int _uiTimer?
```

I think _uiTimer is the way to go (the other option seems lame) but I am interested to see if I am missing something.

Best answer would be a link to a doc that says that acronyms should all keep the same case in C# naming (or something like it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft's *Framework Design Guidelines* have the following to say on this topic:

---

**3.1.2 Capitalizing acronyms**

> ***DO** capitalize both characters of two-character acronyms, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.*
>
> ```
> System.IO
> public void StartIO(Stream ioStream)
> ```
>
> ***DO** capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more characters, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.*
>
> ```
> System.Xml
> public void ProcessHtmlTag(string htmlTag)
> ```
>
> ***DO NOT** capitalize any of the characters of any acronyms, whatever their length, at the beginning of a camel-cased identifier.*

---

You've basically asked about the last of these three rules.

I personally would also opt for `uiTimer`, simply because `uITimer` looks less readable.

Comment: would you apply these rules to the acronyms B2B or A2Z? The second rule should probably apply in this case, but B2b or A2z looks very odd

Comment: _@Andronicus_, I believe it's these cases where exceptions to the above guidelines will creep in. I would probably write `B2B` if it isn't followed by anything else, but `B2b` when something else follows, e.g. `B2bFoo` (in order to make word boundaries easily recognisable). But I'm not certain. -- Another good case where Microsoft themselves were unsure how to capitalize is `ID` vs. `Id`.